# Rails + Resque: Error not going away after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

I have a background job being run by Resque and I the process begins correctly but then I see the error:

```
Error
undefined method `path' for #<Hash:0x007f1900c25298>
/app/app/models/weigh_in.rb:373:in `import_without_check'
/app/app/jobs/uploads.rb:8:in `perform'
```

and initially this was an error but I've since updated my file and completely removed this line, pushed to heroku, restarted heroku as well as redis, yet still the error persists.

Here's the function being called in `app/models/weigh_in`:

```
def self.import_without_check(file, location_id) 

    error = []
    success = []

    options = {:key_mapping => @new_hash, :strings_as_keys => true, :keep_original_headers => true, :remove_unmapped_keys => true}

    SmarterCSV.process(file, options) do |row|

        hashed_row = row[0]
        next if hashed_row[:scale_id].blank? || hashed_row[:scale_id].nil?
        hashed_row[:unique_scale] = location_id + hashed_row[:scale_id].to_s
        hashed_row = hashed_row.to_hash.except!(nil).as_json
        p hashed_row

        client = Client.select('id', 'name').find_by(unique_scale: hashed_row['unique_scale']) || Client.select('id', 'name').find_by(unique_mb: hashed_row['unique_scale'])

        if client.nil?
            error << hashed_row
            next
        end

        hashed_row['client_id'] = client.id
        program_id = client.programs.last.id

        if program_id.nil? || hashed_row['client_id'].nil?
            error << hashed_row
            next
        end

        check_in = CheckIn.new(client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: 'Standard', program_id: program_id)

        unless hashed_row['date'].blank? || hashed_row['date'].nil?
            p 'date', hashed_row['date']
            hashed_row['date'] = Date.strptime(hashed_row["date"], "%m/%d/%y").strftime()
        end

        hashed_row.except!("unique_scale")

        if check_in.save
            hashed_row['check_in_id'] = check_in.id
        end

        if hashed_row['check_in_id'].nil?
            error << hashed_row
            next
        end

        weigh_in = WeighIn.new(hashed_row)
        p weigh_in.valid?, weigh_in.errors.full_messages, weigh_in.errors

        if weigh_in.save
            success << hashed_row
        end

    end

    return success, error
end
```

**Is there something I need to do to make this error go away?**

Comment: Please use `byebug` to debug and please post `/app/app/models/weigh_in.rb`

Comment: I've added the function being called

Comment: Also, it works fine locally, I only see an issue with my production app

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by connecting to the redis Heroku add-on via it's cli, then getting its clients, killing all connections, and restarting my heroku dynos.  Once this was done, my changes were recorded:

```
$ heroku redis:cli
21579> client list                     # Returns clients
21579> client kill 10.159.107.79:43434 # use number from addr property returned with client list command
21579> quit                            # Exit cli
$ heroku restart
```

I hope this helps someone else